# Neo4J Cypher - Restrict Only One Relationship for a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I am fairly new to Neo4J, and have been trying to build a social network app using Cypher queries as annotated queries in Spring Neo4J.

How can I restrict the user node to have only one relationship with the address node using a cypher command/query or any configuration? Basically, I don't want the user to have multiple address relationships.

Comment: You can't do this yet from the neo4j side, although I think you can from the SpringDataNeo4j side. We'll see what the Spring guys say.

Comment: Can the Create Unique statement be used in any way in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [`TransactionEventHandler`](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html). A TransactionEventHandler is a component written in Java and registered with your graphDatabaseService instance. In it's `beforeCommit` you can veto the transaction.

Be warned, writing and using TransactionEventHandler is a advanced concept in Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

You can model your User entity like this:

```
@NodeEntity 
public class User {

@GraphId Long id;

@Indexed String name;

@RelatedTo(type="ADDRESS")
Address address;

}
```

Then SDN will make sure that there is only one `ADDRESS` relationship from an `User` to an `Address`.

Comment: Cool.. But in case I try to create a new relationship address, will the new relationship override the previous address ?

Comment: I tried the same, but for me too, it is creating a new relationship instead of deleting the first one and then creating, it is keeping both the relationships in DB.